# Fill Parent on Horizontal List Row with Margin

Tags: android, listview, margin, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

Okay so I have a horizontal Relative Layout on a ListView and I want a margin between the different Rows on the ListView but I have one problem. I have a button that is being pushed to the far right and I want the click zone to be as big as possible. If there was no margin on the root element of relative layout I would be fine and my button would take up the entire height of the row. But the problem is because there is margin there is an opportunity for the user to click above and below the button where the margin is to trigger the OnItemClick event which isn't the desired functionality of the button which could get frustrating at times.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/list_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/btn"
        android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated obviously its possible I just can't see it sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this is to wrap the ImageButton in a transparent layoutview (relative, linear, frame - depending on your needs) that *does* take up the whole space (i.e. android:layout_width and android:layout_height are fill_parent). Then add the same click handler to the outer layout as you do for the button.

Comment: I did it in my app. A note that `match_parent` is better, `fill_parent` is deprecated.

Comment: So I nested a FrameLayout inside of the RelativeLayout and pushed it to the right using alignParentRight and it still doesn't fill the entire height. As well I should probably mention the actual layout of my file is <LinearLayout><RelativeLayout> </RelativeLayout></LinearLayout> With the top LinearLayout being match_parent for both width and height.